# Error "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading", While uploading .docx file

Tags: file, upload, connection, reset, docx

I am getting "**The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading**" error, while uploading a **.docx** format file. This is happening in all the browsers.

Uploading pdf, zip file formats are working perfectly.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how it can be resolved ?

Comment: What service are you trying to upload the .docx to?   More information on your issue would be helpful.

Comment: The web site is hosted in godaddy. From 21st July 2016, I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a simple html upload page and see if it is possible to upload a .docx file. If it works, then your application code needs further troubleshooting and if by making a simple html upload page the error still persists; then your application code needs no changing, please do contact Godaddy hosting support for server support with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am still having this issue with GoDaddy hosting which no longer allows uploads of some docx files. For now, a workaround is just to "Save as..." an older word .doc format which for me seems to work.